# Razor: Write to website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to build up a javascript array using razorcode. The final javascript code should look like this:

```
var data = [[10, 20], [30, 40]];
```

So I think I should do something like this:

```
var data = [
    @foreach (Data d in Model.data)
    {
            [d.a, d.b]
    }
];
```

However the central [d.a, d.b]: C# compiler thinks I want to do something in c#, but I simply want the [ ] and the , written to the website at that position, including the values from the model that Ive adressed there.

How do I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var data = [
    @foreach (Data d in Model.data)
    {
            @Html.Raw(string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", d.a, d.b));
    }
];
```